# Error in ArgoCD for remote branch after deploying using Kustomize

Tags: git, azure-devops, kustomize, argocd

Using Azure DevOps for our Git Repository and Deployment Pipelines, which will deploy to AKS and managed by ArgoCD

I reconfigured the branching strategy for our environment, where we have a branch per environment; test, perf and prod.

However it appears an old branch that doesn't exist in Git anymore is causing an error. The branch was `perf/from-master-nov-24` and when the deployment to ArgoCD occurs this error appears while trying to sync.

```
ComparisonError: rpc error: code = Internal desc = Failed to fetch 73c230cf4c56ec8682750ab5e8a04bf494cd0362: 
`git fetch origin --tags --force` failed exit status 1: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/perf': 'refs/remotes/origin/perf/from-master-nov-24' exists;
cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/perf' From https://dev.azure.com/<organisation>/<project>/_git/!<repository> [new branch] perf -> origin/perf (unable to update local ref) 
error: some local refs could not be updated; try running 'git remote prune origin' to remove any old, conflicting branches
```

`perf` used to be a directory which has since been deleted, and now there is a branch called `perf`.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I've tried running `git remote prune origin --dry-run` but the offending branch doesn't appear in the output.

Comment: `git remote prune origin` or `git fetch --prune origin` should indeed fix the problem, but you must run this within the repository in which the problem occurs (there might be dozens of clones splashed about, where only some of them have the issue in the first place).

Comment: Possibly related issue: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/9645